Valididity of information based solution to Monty Hall problem
The hypothesis: the probability that you will win by using the best strategy is equivalent how well you would do if you were given the minimum amount of information Monty needs to know.
Ex. In the normal Monty hall problem, the host obviously needs to know where 1 goat is. He also needs to know where the 2nd goat is, but only if you pick the 1st goat. Therefore, there is a 2/3 chance he needs to know where the first goat is, and 1/3 chance he needs to know where both goats are. If you know where 1 goat is, you have 50% of winning, if you know where 2 goats are, you have 100% of winning.
(2/3) * 50% + (1/3) * 100% = 2/3 chance using the optimal strategy.
For n doors, with n-1 goats. Monty reveals m doors, and you pick from the rest.
Monty needs to know where at least m goats are. If you pick any of the m goats, he needs to know m+1 goats.
[(n-m)/n] * [1/(n-m)] + [m/n] * [1/(n-m-1)] = [n-1]/[n*(n-m-1)]
This is the same answer other people obtained for the generalized Monty Hall problem.
This doesn't tell you what the optimal strategy is, but it seems pretty intuitive that the best option is to switch every time.
Is this method valid, and is it useful to solve other probability/game theory problems?

I am confused.  I would have thought you are given the information: Monty knows the location of $m$ goats which are not behind the door you have chosen, and then opens those doors to show you.

Your calculation of the probability of Monty needing to know a number of goats is exactly the ordinary calculation of your probability of winning. All you've done is changed how the calculation is described. I don't see it as being any more obvious or intuitive than the original calculation myself, but maybe it is to others.
